# Match @Input() with a defined list in Angular

Tags: angular, validation, typescript, input

What is the best practice to check if a user input is in a whitelist of entries?

```
export class myClass {
  @Input() type: string;
}
```

To set `type` should be only possible if it is in a defined list, otherwhise it should be empty. Is there a common way with angular or typescript?

Comment: Use a private property to store the validated input. And take a look to getter and setter for validating your input.

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of a private instance field and a getter/setter for the `@Input`. Like this:

```
export class myClass {
    private validType: string;

    @Input()
    public set type(value: string) {
       if(this.validate(value)) {
          this.validType = type;
       } else {
          this.validType = '';
       }
    }

    public get type() {
       return this.validType;
    }

    private validate(value: string) {
       // do your validation here
       return true;
    }
}
```

This makes sure that everytime the input property changes, it's getting checked my a validation method (I used `validate` as a name for this example). And if you're using the type property you will always get the validated property `validType`.

If you're handling form inputs you should definitly define your own **[validator](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validation)** for such a task and apply it to the form fields.